# Changing the style of specific records in GridView

Tags: asp.net, gridview, format, aspxgridview

I'm designing a logistics system in ASP.Net . In the Order processing page, orders are displayed by Grid View,i want to change the font style of the rows to BOLD, which are marked as"ordedr not processed". thanks.

[image: order processing page]

Comment: Use Row databound Event check the order status then set the specific cell style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        string OrStatus = Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Orderstatus"));
        if (OrStatus == "Order not processed")
        {
            //You can use whatever you want to play with rows
            e.Row.Cells[0].Font.Bold = true;
            e.Row.Cells[2].CssClass = "gridcss";
        }
    }
}
```

Follow that code. It will helps

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in "rowdatabound" event of grid.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            GridView grid = GridView1;
            GridViewRow row = e.Row;
            if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {

               string orderstatus= Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Orderstatus"));
              if(orderstatus=="Order not processed)
              {
                   //write your code to change css
              }
            }
        }
```